# How to format date according to local formatting wit MomentJS?

Tags: momentjs

With [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) how can I format a date according to the local datetime format?

Currently I display the time as follows:

```
var zone = moment.tz.guess();
var usertime = moment.tz(ucttime, zone).format('LLL');
```

But when changing the zone to `Asia/Seoul` I still get the American formatting using AM/PM:

```
January 30, 2018 11:37 AM
```

Basically I'm looking for JavaScript's `toLocaleDateString()` equivalent.

I've tried the following, but the output is wrong:

```
var usertime = moment.tz(ucttime, zone).toDate().toLocaleString();
```

Which outputs (for Asia/Seoul):

```
1/29/2018, 6:32:37 PM
```

While it should be:

```
2018. 1. 29. 오후 6:32
```

**Update:**

This displays the correct formatting, but breaks the timezone ajustment:

```
usertime = moment.tz(ucttime, zone).toDate().toLocaleString(navigator.language);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have referenced `moment.js`, `locale/ko.js`, `moment-timezone-with-data.js`, you can use this format:

```
moment.tz(moment(), moment.tz.guess()).locale('ko').format('YYYY. M. DD. a H:mm')
```

Comment: Yes, but this needs to happen automatically for each locale, not hard coded.

Comment: then `LLL` is your needed common format, but it doesn't look like what you want: `2018년 1월 30일 오전 10:17`

Comment: That's correct, LLL does not return the right formatting for Korea. Could be a bug.

Comment: I think `moment.js` allows you update locale to customize the format `LLL`

Comment: That's correct, but does that mean I'm dealing with a bug here for Korea? Or is it wrong for all other locales as well?

Comment: Well, datetime standards are defined by some organizations. And I guess that the guy who collects data in `locale/ko.js` follows a standard different from yours :D

Comment: Seems completely off from the standards described by IBM: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSS28S_8.1.0/XFDL/i_xfdl_r_formats_ko_KR.html